# When are transactions stored (to disk)?

Tags: transaction, iri-node, database

Are transactions only stored to RocksDB after confirmation? 
And unconfirmed tx are just passed around between neighbors and kept in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [current IRI (1.4.1.7)](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L252), the transaction is stored in the DB when it is received and if and only if it is **valid**.

But don't misunderstand the term **valid**. It means that the transaction has:

- an acceptable timestamp
- an acceptable value field
- a valid signature
- a valid nonce (i.e. the Weight Magnitude must be at least the min weight magnitude, or in other words: check that the POW was done)

A valid, but unconfirmed transaction is stored in DB when it is received.